# Specify a lower resolution for video feed

Tags: webrtc, opentok, tokbox

When using tokbox, how does one decrease the video stream resolution while keeping the video dimensions the same, in order to avoid hogging the CPU?

Answer (score 1):

specify a lower resolution [as described in the API](https://www.tokbox.com/developer/guides/publish-stream/js/#setting_resolution) and use CSS on the video element to specify the width/height so the dimensions do not automatically adapt to the resolution of the video stream.

Comment: When aspect's the same you don't even need CSS, just specify a fixed width and height on the video element.